# Laravel 4 eager loading and categories, subcategories, articles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eager-loading

Hi i thought i can handle this myself, but actually i don't know how to bite it.

I am trying to categorise my programs. There will be only 2 levels of categories:

1 CATEGORY
2 |-Subcategory

I want it to be as simple as possible.
- program can belong to only one subcategory,
- categories can have many subcategories,
- subcategories can have many programs,

Of course i would like to list all programs from subcategories, when someone choose a main category.

I am also not sure about my current database tables structure and relationship in models.

Tables in database:

**programs**: id, title, description, program_subcategory_id
**programs_categories**: id, name
**programs_subcategories**: id, name, program_category_id

Models:
**Program.php**

```
class Program extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'programs';
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
    public function subcategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('ProgramSubcategory', 'program_subcategory_id');
    }   
}
```

**ProgramCategory.php**

```
class ProgramCategory extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'programs_categories';
    public function subcategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ProgramSubcategory');
    }
}
```

**ProgramSubcategory.php**

```
class ProgramSubcategory extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'programs_subcategories';
    public function programs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Program');
    }
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('ProgramCategory');
    }
}
```

Actual controllers:
**ProgramsController.php**

```
class ProgramsController extends BaseController {
    public function index()
    {
        $programs = Program::with('subcategory')->orderBy('programs.id', 'desc')->paginate(5);    
        $acategories = ArticleCategory::All();
        $pcategories = ProgramCategory::All();
        return View::make('programs.index', compact('programs', 'acategories', 'pcategories'));
    }
}
```

**ProgramsSubcatecories.php**

```
class ProgramsSubcategories extends BaseController {
    public function index($cname)
    {
        $programs = ProgramSubcategory::whereAlias($cname)->first()->programs()->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
        $pcategories = ProgramCategory::All();
        $scategories = ProgramSubcategory::All();
        $acategories = ArticleCategory::All();
        return View::make('programs.index', compact('programs', 'pcategories', 'scategories ', 'acategories'));
    }
    public function show($cname, $id)
    {
        $category = ProgramSubcategory::whereAlias($cname)->first();
        $program = $category->programs()->findOrFail($id);
        $pcategories = ProgramCategory::All();
        $acategories = ArticleCategory::All();
        return View::make('programs.show', compact('program', 'category', 'pcategories', 'scategories ', 'acategories'));
    }
}
```

It is not a problem for me to list all items from one category with eager loading. But i have problem how to do it with 2-levels categories.

Please advise how to start it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking for `eager loading`, you need to solve how to manage hierarchical data in your database.

**Nested sets** model serves this purpose very well. You should read some theory on Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Fortunately, there are Eloquent implementations already.
To mention some:
- Baum (the best free, imho), https://github.com/etrepat/baum
- Laravel Nested Set, https://github.com/atrauzzi/laravel-nested-set
- Laravel4-nestedset, https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel4-nestedset

and the paid one (surely highest quality as well)
from Cartalyst company - https://cartalyst.com/manual/nested-sets

Comment: I see Baum would be the best here. But it doesn't support Laravel 4.1 which i am using. Do i really need to use nested set? Isn't there any other way?

Comment: I would go for Nested sets only - since this model does not require recursion to retrieve tree and it means it's fast, can be done on database server.

Comment: I've chosen nested set of lazychaser. Please correct me if i'm wrong. Just to be clear for me :) If i want to use nested set, intead of 2 tables in my database (**programs_categories** and **programs_subcatecories**) i need to use only one now, just **categories**. Also, instead of two models **Category.php** and **Subcategory.php** i need only one **Category.php**. Also i'm a little bit confused how to set the order of my categories for the use of nested set.

Comment: Yes, you are right! After all, even subcategory is category. It is child category to its parent but parent category to its child. This model helps you track this hierarchy.

Comment: Everything's clear now :) Thank you very much @Andreyco!